# Reading text from label

Tags: c#, winforms

I have just a little problem with reading text from label, but...

I have two forms. **Form_1**, and Form_2.

Form_1 is sending (on demand) text from **"label_one"** directly to "label_two" in Form_2.

But in Form_2 i have another label called "label_reader" that need to show any changes done in "label_two" text.

I must (dynamically?) read any changes from "label_two" and show it in label_reader.

Never had a similar problem, and have no idea how to do that. It can't be done with the use of a button.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to register to the `TextChanged` **event** of `label_two`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data Between Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464625/passing-data-between-forms)

Comment: You should add some sample code to show what you are currently doing. But it sounds like you are updating label_two directly from Form_1. Instead, you should post the text from Label_one to a property on Form_2 - That way, you can update both labels in one operation.

Comment: @ASh don't think it's a duplicate, as this is about two labels in the _same_ form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `TextChanged` event of `label_two`. Subscribe to that event (most likely in the constructor of your `Form_2`) and set the text of `label_reader` when the event is raised:

```
public partial class Form_2 : Form
{
   //...

   public Form_2()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       // your other code

       label_two.TextChanged += label_two_TextChanged;
   }

   // the event handler
   private void label_two_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label_reader.Text = label_two.Text; // or what ever you want to do
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you René, you just made my day :) so crazy simple.

Comment: +1; `label_two.TextChanged += (_s, _e) => label_reader.Text = label_two.Text;` is shorter and may be useful since it can't be (erroneously) removed.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes I like that one, too. But as I wasn't sure if OP is going to do some more inside the handler and how experienced s/he is, I wanted to keep things simple and not introduce other technologies all at once.